# Testing Highcharts with protractorjs/Selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium, highcharts, protractor

I am using protractorjs to test a site built with angular.
The angular site generates a lot charts using Highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/.

I am finding it difficult to test these charts via protractorjs for EtoE testing. 
Does anyone know a better way of testing Highcharts with 
protractor or any other testing tools.

```
What I am basically looking is for checking whether the 
-highchart was loaded on the page, 
-checking if the toolstip show data from the JSON file
-The number of bars showing on the highchart have correct values fetched from the JSON. 
- Extracting the Highchart JSON from the server response.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make the question more specific providing a link to the website with highcharts and the desired actions you'd like your test to perform? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a ton of details here, but I use RSpec against an Angular project just like yours that also uses highcharts.

Your charts should be in a div somewhere with an id.  In my app it's wrapped in .highcharts-container.  You can wait on those to appear and assert against them.

There should be a class named .highcharts-tooltip that you can find and assert against a specific value as well.